# TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am receiving a "TypeError" error with the following code.

```
for(var i =0; i<60; i++) {
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
function postData() {
    fetch('https://www.oneblockdown.it/index.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'controller': 'auth',
            'action': 'register',
            'extension': 'obd',
            'email': generateName1()+'@*******',
            'password': '********',
            'firstName': generateName1(),
            'lastName': generateName2(),
            'birthDate': '1992-6-11',
            'sex': 'MALE',
            'privacy[1]': '1',
            'privacy[2]': '0',
            'version': '100'
        })
    })
};


function capFirst(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function generateName1(){
    var name1 = ["Harry","Ross",
    "Bruce","Cook","Carolyn","Morgan","Albert","Walker","Randy","Reed",
    "Larry","Barnes","Lois","Wilson","Jesse","Campbell","Ernest","Rogers",
    "Theresa","Patterson","Henry","Simmons","Michelle","Perry","Frank","Butler","Shirley","Brooks","Rachel","Edwards","Christopher","Perez",
    "Thomas","Baker","Sara","Moore","Chris","Bailey","Roger","Johnson",
    "Marilyn","Thompson","Anthony","Evans","Julie","Hall","Paula","Phillips","Annie","Hernandez","Dorothy","Murphy","Alice","Howard",
    "Ruth","Jackson","Debra","Allen","Gerald","Harris","Raymond","Carter",
    "Jacqueline","Torres","Joseph","Nelson","Carlos","Sanchez","Ralph","Clark","Jean","Alexander","Stephen","Roberts","Eric","Long","Amanda","Scott","Teresa","Diaz","Wanda","Thomas"];
    var name = capFirst(name1[getRandomInt(0, name1.length + 1)]);

    return name;
}
function generateName2(){

    var name2 =[ "Anderson", "Ashwoon", "Aikin", "Bateman", "Bongard", "Bowers", "Boyd", "Cannon", "Cast", "Deitz", "Dewalt", "Ebner", "Frick", "Hancock", "Haworth", "Hesch", "Hoffman", "Kassing", "Knutson", "Lawless", "Lawicki", "Mccord", "McCormack", "Miller", "Myers", "Nugent", "Ortiz", "Orwig", "Ory", "Paiser", "Pak", "Pettigrew", "Quinn", "Quizoz", "Ramachandran", "Resnick", "Sagar", "Schickowski", "Schiebel", "Sellon", "Severson", "Shaffer", "Solberg", "Soloman", "Sonderling", "Soukup", "Soulis", "Stahl", "Sweeney", "Tandy", "Trebil", "Trusela", "Trussel", "Turco", "Uddin", "Uflan", "Ulrich", "Upson", "Vader", "Vail", "Valente", "Van Zandt", "Vanderpoel", "Ventotla", "Vogal", "Wagle", "Wagner", "Wakefield", "Weinstein", "Weiss", "Woo", "Yang", "Yates", "Yocum", "Zeaser", "Zeller", "Ziegler", "Bauer", "Baxster", "Casal", "Cataldi", "Caswell", "Celedon", "Chambers", "Chapman", "Christensen", "Darnell", "Davidson", "Davis", "DeLorenzo", "Dinkins", "Doran", "Dugelman", "Dugan", "Duffman", "Eastman", "Ferro", "Ferry", "Fletcher", "Fietzer", "Hylan", "Hydinger", "Illingsworth", "Ingram", "Irwin", "Jagtap", "Jenson", "Johnson", "Johnsen", "Jones", "Jurgenson", "Kalleg", "Kaskel", "Keller", "Leisinger", "LePage", "Lewis", "Linde", "Lulloff", "Maki", "Martin", "McGinnis", "Mills", "Moody", 
   "Moore", "Napier", "Nelson", "Norquist", "Nuttle", "Olson", 
   "Ostrander", 
  "Reamer", "Reardon", "Reyes", "Rice", "Ripka", "Roberts", "Rogers", 
   "Root", 
  "Sandstrom", "Sawyer", "Schlicht", "Schmitt", "Schwager", "Schutz", 
  "Schuster", "Tapia", "Thompson", "Tiernan", "Tisler" ]; 

    var name12 = capFirst(name2[getRandomInt(0, name2.length + 1)]);
    return name12;``
}

postData();   
}
```

Here is the error in full:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined
>       at capFirst (c:\Users\Billy\nodejs\OBDnew (1).js:28:23)
>       at generateName1 (c:\Users\Billy\nodejs\OBDnew (1).js:44:20)
>       at postData (c:\Users\Billy\nodejs\OBDnew (1).js:13:26)
>       at Object. (c:\Users\Billy\nodejs\OBDnew (1).js:56:5)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)

Comment: With this line: `name2[getRandomInt(0, name2.length + 1)]` you will eventually fall out of the bounds of the array. Use `name2[getRandomInt(0, name2.length - 1)]` instead.

Comment: so you need our help spamming someone else's site?

Comment: Thanks for the reply man! I get this when I try to run after saving what you said..

[Running] node "c:\Users\Billy\nodejs\OBDnew (1).js"
c:\Users\Billy\nodejs\OBDnew (1).js:28
        return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);

Comment: @georg its not really spamming the site, its just creating multiple accounts :/ not that deep

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine . Take a look :

```js
function capFirst(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function generateName1(){
    var name1 = ["Harry","Ross",
    "Bruce","Cook","Carolyn","Morgan","Albert","Walker","Randy","Reed",
    "Larry","Barnes","Lois","Wilson","Jesse","Campbell","Ernest","Rogers",
    "Theresa","Patterson","Henry","Simmons","Michelle","Perry","Frank","Butler","Shirley","Brooks","Rachel","Edwards","Christopher","Perez",
    "Thomas","Baker","Sara","Moore","Chris","Bailey","Roger","Johnson",
    "Marilyn","Thompson","Anthony","Evans","Julie","Hall","Paula","Phillips","Annie","Hernandez","Dorothy","Murphy","Alice","Howard",
    "Ruth","Jackson","Debra","Allen","Gerald","Harris","Raymond","Carter",
    "Jacqueline","Torres","Joseph","Nelson","Carlos","Sanchez","Ralph","Clark","Jean","Alexander","Stephen","Roberts","Eric","Long","Amanda","Scott","Teresa","Diaz","Wanda","Thomas"];
    var name = capFirst(name1[getRandomInt(0, name1.length + 1)]);

    return name;
}
function generateName2(){

    var name2 =[ "Anderson", "Ashwoon", "Aikin", "Bateman", "Bongard", "Bowers", "Boyd", "Cannon", "Cast", "Deitz", "Dewalt", "Ebner", "Frick", "Hancock", "Haworth", "Hesch", "Hoffman", "Kassing", "Knutson", "Lawless", "Lawicki", "Mccord", "McCormack", "Miller", "Myers", "Nugent", "Ortiz", "Orwig", "Ory", "Paiser", "Pak", "Pettigrew", "Quinn", "Quizoz", "Ramachandran", "Resnick", "Sagar", "Schickowski", "Schiebel", "Sellon", "Severson", "Shaffer", "Solberg", "Soloman", "Sonderling", "Soukup", "Soulis", "Stahl", "Sweeney", "Tandy", "Trebil", "Trusela", "Trussel", "Turco", "Uddin", "Uflan", "Ulrich", "Upson", "Vader", "Vail", "Valente", "Van Zandt", "Vanderpoel", "Ventotla", "Vogal", "Wagle", "Wagner", "Wakefield", "Weinstein", "Weiss", "Woo", "Yang", "Yates", "Yocum", "Zeaser", "Zeller", "Ziegler", "Bauer", "Baxster", "Casal", "Cataldi", "Caswell", "Celedon", "Chambers", "Chapman", "Christensen", "Darnell", "Davidson", "Davis", "DeLorenzo", "Dinkins", "Doran", "Dugelman", "Dugan", "Duffman", "Eastman", "Ferro", "Ferry", "Fletcher", "Fietzer", "Hylan", "Hydinger", "Illingsworth", "Ingram", "Irwin", "Jagtap", "Jenson", "Johnson", "Johnsen", "Jones", "Jurgenson", "Kalleg", "Kaskel", "Keller", "Leisinger", "LePage", "Lewis", "Linde", "Lulloff", "Maki", "Martin", "McGinnis", "Mills", "Moody", 
   "Moore", "Napier", "Nelson", "Norquist", "Nuttle", "Olson", 
   "Ostrander", 
  "Reamer", "Reardon", "Reyes", "Rice", "Ripka", "Roberts", "Rogers", 
   "Root", 
  "Sandstrom", "Sawyer", "Schlicht", "Schmitt", "Schwager", "Schutz", 
  "Schuster", "Tapia", "Thompson", "Tiernan", "Tisler" ]; 

    var name12 = capFirst(name2[getRandomInt(0, name2.length + 1)]);
    return name12;``
}


 console.log( generateName2() )
```